# Notions of injective graded modules

Tags: abstract-algebra

$\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}\def\IHom{\underline{\Hom}}$
Let $G$ be a group, $A$ be a $G$-graded algebra over a field $k$ and $M$ and $N$ be graded $A$-modules. If necessary, one may assume that all modules considered have $k$-finite dimensional graded components. I am wondering what the injective modules are. It seems to me that there exist some different notions, which seem to arise from the different Hom-functors one can consider. Let $\Hom_A(M, N)$ the space homogeneous module homorphisms, and let $\IHom_A(M, N)$ be the graded $A$-module with components $\IHom_A(M, N)_g = \Hom_A(M, N[g])$. These give rise to

1. Modules $J$ for which $\Hom_A(-, J)$ is exact. Equivalently, these are modules that satisfy the usual lifting property in the category of graded $A$-modules.
2. Modules $J$ for which $\IHom_A(-, J)$ is exact.

These seem to behave differently under taking the $k$-dual $A$-module $J^* = \IHom_k(J, k)$. Is it true that

1. The $k$-dual of a $\Hom_A$-injective module is $\Hom_A$-projective? This seems to follow by taking the $k$-dual of the lifting diagram defining projectivity and injectivity.
2. The $k$-dual of a $\IHom_A$-injective is flat, with respect to the graded tensor product $\underline{\otimes}_A$ over $A$? This seems to follow from the adjunction between $\underline{\otimes}_A$ and $\IHom_A$.

How do all these notions relate to the ungraded analogues? I know that a graded module is projective in the category of graded $A$-modules iff it is projective in the category of all $A$-modules. What can be said about graded injective and graded flat modules?